# Non-parametric estimator - CVaR / Expected shortfall

Tags: risk, portfolio-management, risk-management, cvar

Is the estimation of the CVaR using known non-parametric methods (histogram, kernels) different than the estimation of any other R.V.?

If the answer is yes, I am interested to know whether there are some non-parametric methods for CVaR estimation which are also consistent.

Thanks

Comment: what is R.V.? What do you mean by  consistent estimator for Expected Shortfall? As if sounds like most CVAR estimators are not consistent??

Comment: Probably R.V. = Random Variable

Comment: I would say that it's not different at all. Cut your losses sample at the chosen quantile and average the result.